# find and replace .\ with .@ {\/ using TCL scripts

Tags: tcl

Please help to modify below line using TCL scripts

from

```
top.dut.fe.stk.pma.phy.phy0.pma.dig.lane0.asic_xface.\range_counter_reg[0]
```

to

```
top.dut.fe.stk.pma.phy.phy0.pma.dig.lane0.asic_xface.@ {\/range_counter_reg[0]}.Q
```

tried using find and replace but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`regsub`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm) -- `regsub {.\\(.+)} $from {.@ {/\1}.Q}`

```
set from {top.dut.fe.stk.pma.phy.phy0.pma.dig.lane0.asic_xface.\range_counter_reg[0]}
set to [regsub {.\\(.+)} $from {.@ {/\1}.Q}]
puts $from; puts $to
```

```
top.dut.fe.stk.pma.phy.phy0.pma.dig.lane0.asic_xface.\range_counter_reg[0]
top.dut.fe.stk.pma.phy.phy0.pma.dig.lane0.asic_xface.@ {/range_counter_reg[0]}.Q
```